# Standard Deviation of Custom Variable in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Given a custom variable taking two values demarcating two potential alternative designs for a page, is it possible to extract standard deviation or other measures of distribution for metrics (pages/visit and duration/visit specifically) for those pages?

Yes, I know content experiments is far better suit to this type of problem, but for undiscloseable reasons, CE is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I've haven't seen a solution specifically for the metrics you describe, however I have seen [one for goal completions](http://www.michaelwhitaker.com/blog/2011/11/02/stats-calculator-google-analytics/). You might just have to export the data to Excel or SPSS to get what you need.